# how to select first item in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi my friend i have one question how to select first item in list in java script?

```js
document.getElementById("mySelect").value[0])
```

is Right?

Comment: You are asking about solution in jacascript? Why did you added jQuery tag..

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "select"

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select id='mySelect'>
   <option value='11'>1</option>
   <option value='22'>2</option>
   <option value='33'>3</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
var list = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var value = list.options[0].getAttribute('value');
var text = list.options[0].innerHTML;
console.log(value); // 11
console.log(text); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't read carefully.. thought he was talkin about ul or ol.. correcting for correctness' sake. don't accept this as answer.

```
    var list = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var value = list.options[0].getAttribute('value');
    var text = list.options[0].innerHTML;

    alert(value);
    alert(text);
```

This is Mahedi Sabuj's answer first, so accept his if this was what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will definitely help you.

```
document.getElementById("theId").selectedIndex = 0;
```